# Add WP permalink to PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, rss

The code below adds an image into my wordpress RSS feed. I am wanting to make it so that the image is automatically hyperlinked back to the corresponding post. The code is in my theme's functions.php

```
    function wcs_post_thumbnails_in_feeds( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $content = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) . '<span class="text">' . $content . '</span>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'wcs_post_thumbnails_in_feeds' );
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wcs_post_thumbnails_in_feeds' );
Can I change this so that the post_thumbnail is automatically wrapped with a link to the post?
```

How can I wrap the ***get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )*** part of the code with a link? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the get_permalink function and pass it the post ID.

```
function wcs_post_thumbnails_in_feeds( $content ) {
        global $post;
        if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
            $content = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) . '</a><span class="text">' . $content . '</span>';
        }
        return $content;
    }
```